# How to run webdriver and JMeter code in Eclipse using Java

Tags: java, jmeter, webdriver, jmeter-plugins

Below is my requirement :
(1)I need to do UI performance testing .
(2)At the end of the test I want jmx file to be generated,I do have the batch file that will convert it to jtl and then to html report.

Answers not known :
(1)I did browse through  a lot of links that explained how to execute webdriver code using JUnit in JMeter. However I don't want to do that[run webdriver code in JMeter] and want my code to be a standalone code using HTMLUnit(headless browser) performing authentication and then the remaining click actions[Click on multiple links] ....Behind the scenes jmeter should record performance of every page and at end of test ,dump the results.Also it should be irrespective of testng /junit .Does anyone know if this is possible and can redirect me to the appropriate link.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

JMeter has nothing in common with the UI performance testing, as per [JMeter main page](http://jmeter.apache.org/):

> **JMeter is not a browser**, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, **JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does** (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

Both [JUnit](https://junit.org/junit5/) and [TestNG](https://testng.org/doc/index.html) automatically record function execution duration, you can build your test in such a way that measurable actions would be annotated with [`@Test`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Test.html) annotation so the time will be automatically recorded.

In addition you can consider using [Navigation Timing API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation_timing_API) from your WebDriver tests in order to get more information regarding page loading events.

---

If you still want to run JMeter tests from Java code - check out [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) article, it covers both running existing .jmx file and creating a new JMeter test purely using [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) from Java, however it is not applicable for your use case. The recommended way is to:

1. Create the main load using JMeter
2. Measure client-side performance using Selenium